# How to catch a check_box_tag value inside my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, model

I have a checkbox in my view

```
<%= check_box_tag 'email_checker', 'selected' %>
```

If this checkbox is selected, I want to do a specific action in my function. The function that I'm customizing is inside the model. Below the 'if' that I want to customize using the value of checkbox.

```
if ????
    notified = []
    # Author and assignee are always notified unless they have been
    # locked or don't want to be notified
    notified << author if author
    ...
```

How can I get the checkbox value from my view and use it value in my model function?

**PS:** I have already tried to use: `params[:email_checker]` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your email_checker model, you can just refer to selected.  You can't refer to params in the model.  So for example, your email_checker.rb model might look like this:

```
attr_accessible :selected

before_save :some_function_using_selected #or you can use whichever callback is appropriate for that function

def some_function_using_selected
    if selected == true    #assuming your field is a boolean
        # your code
    end
end
```